# How to create such jelly type animation in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-animation

how to create such jelly type animation in bottom nav bar, may be you know examples. please see attached giphy link:

[image]

Comment: Could you please look at this two link - https://fluttergems.dev/packages/expandable_bottom_bar/ https://fluttergems.dev/packages/floating_bottom_bar/

Comment: @DevPankajPatel yes, I've already seen them, but they've no that, jelly effect

Comment: Do you need exactly the same as Giphy?

Comment: yes, exact same

Answer (score 1):

You would need to use a custom `GestureDetector` that provides the current drag/animation progress.
Its child would then be a [`CustomPainter`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/rendering/CustomPainter-class.html) with a custom path.

Comment: Could you provide example this exact animation?

Comment: this would take some time,.. but you can ask follow up questions when you're stuck.